# Getting back the response returned by the Java API when called from html form action using URL

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, netty

I am using Netty Server and Java APIs. I call the Java API using the action field in the form just as shown below:

```
action="http://localhost:8585/ot/admin/upload/mocktest/questionpaper"
```

Now, it runs successfully and a new page is opened with the above link and shows the Json response just as shown below:

```
"Mocktest Id: 196 Total Uploaded Questions: 78"
```

I want to handle this response by taking this response in JavaScript and skip the new page that opens every time. I have to hit the back button to go back to the calling page.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery post to get response form the server and to insert that response inside a DIV.

```
        $.post( "http://localhost:8585/ot/admin/upload/mocktest/questionpaper", function( data ) {
                alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );  //Response from server
        });
```

If you want to send request with form values then you have to use `$( "#formid" ).serialize()`.

```
      $.post( "http://localhost:8585/ot/admin/upload/mocktest/questionpaper", $( "#formid" ).serialize(),function(data){

            alert( "Data" + data ); //Response from server
        });
```

Now your complete code may look like:

```
      $( "#formid" ).submit(function( event ) {

             event.preventDefault(); //to prevent default submission of form

             $.post( "http://localhost:8585/ot/admin/upload/mocktest/questionpaper", $( "#formid" ).serialize(),function(data){

                alert( "Data" + data ); //Response from server
            });


       });
```

For in brief look at [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)